# How to edit certain value in file?

Tags: c, file, int, edit

i want to edit only certain value in file ,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int month[3]={0,0,0};
    int month1;
    printf("\n1.December");
    printf("\n2.November");
    printf("\nEnter month:");
    scanf("%d",&month1);

    if(month1 == 2)
    {
        printf("\nthis is November");
        month[1]=3*5;
        printf("\ntotal for this month is :%d",month[1]);
    }

        else if (month1 == 1)
    {
        printf("\nthis is December");
        month[2]=2*5;
        printf("\ntotal for this month is :%d\n\n\n",month[2]);

    }

    FILE *mo;
    if( (mo = fopen ("month.txt", "w" ) ) == NULL)
        {
        printf ("File unable to open");
        } // end if
    else 
    {
        fprintf(mo,"Transaction for December is %d ",month[2]);
        fprintf(mo,"\nTransaction for November is %d ",month[1]);

    }


return 0;
system("pause");
}
```

Let's say I run this program once and after that , program will store this value in file. 
and below what inside file month.txt

Transaction for December is 10 
Transaction for November is 0

How to make , after i run this program again, value of 10 not change associate with 0 and it automatically update that value.
And make it look like this in file month.txt 
(after i run three time this program)
first i choose 1 second and third i choose 2 ,

Transaction for December is 10 
Transaction for November is 30

Answer (score 1):

There is no predetermined way to do this. Since you have implied that your file is plain unformatted text, you would need to treat the phrases "Transaction for December" and "Transaction for November" as though they were delimiters or tags.

One example of a solution would be to add a `while` loop to the code which scans the entire document, then replaces the necessary string. My suggested implementation would use `fgets` to pull a line which is then analyzed by `strstr`. You could, of course, also use various other functions such as `strtok`.

However, it should be noted that this is not necessarily a safe operation to perform. It would be better to have your program instead copy each line from your source file and print them in a completely different file. The behavior, however, would be roughly the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int month[3] = { 0,0,0 };
    int month1;
    printf("\n1.December");
    printf("\n2.November");
    printf("\nEnter month:");
    scanf("%d", &month1);

    if (month1 == 2)
    {
        printf("\nthis is November");
        month[1] = 3 * 5;
        printf("\ntotal for this month is :%d", month[1]);
    }

    else if (month1 == 1)
    {
        printf("\nthis is December");
        month[2] = 2 * 5;
        printf("\ntotal for this month is :%d\n\n\n", month[2]);

    }

    FILE *mo = fopen("month.txt", "w");
    if (mo == NULL)
    {
        printf("File unable to open");
    } // end if
    else
    {
        // Value to edit
        char phraseToUpdate[] = "Transaction for December is ";
        char currentLine[50];

        // Scan an initial line
        fgets(currentLine, 49, mo);

        // Look at every line of the file
        while (strchr(currentLine, EOF) == NULL)
        {
            // Find your phrase
            if (strstr(currentLine, phraseToUpdate) != NULL)
            {
                // Write to your file
                // You WILL have to modify these to update on the current line
                // fprintf(mo, "Transaction for December is %d ", month[2]);
                // fprintf(mo, "\nTransaction for November is %d ", month[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Put that thing back where it came from (or so help me)
                fprintf(mo, currentLine);
            }

            // Scan next line
            fgets(currentLine, 49, mo);
        }

    }


    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```